# Why can't the plumber fix my kitchen sink?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, sink

I had a professional plumber out today. He spent about 3 hours trying to unclog my kitchen sink. Finally he said there's something wrong with the drain because he can't get it fixed. So here I am with no working sink and I'm not sure what to do now. The company I am working with has offered to bring a camera and have a look around the drain pipes.

Is there anything I can do on my own to try and fix my problem? Why couldn't a professional fix it?

Comment: Did he say what he thought was wrong with the drain?

Comment: Are the other drains in your house also not draining properly?

Comment: sounds like a pretty lazy plumber

Comment: @Steven Not being able to fix a backed up drain in a single visit, does not make the plumber lazy.  Scoping a drain with a camera is a common practice when the drain cannot be easily cleared, and often the company only has one technician and/or camera that can scope the line.

Comment: @Tester101 true but if it took three hours to figure that out I would be asking questions about the "professional plumber"

Comment: yea 3hrs of work plus another visit (billable) time.  if I call a plumber for a drain problem specifically, I expect them to come with the necessary tools

Comment: @UNECS You guys are brutal. Maybe the guy spent 3 hours trying to clear the drain, because he didn't want to leave the customer with a non-functioning sink. Maybe he's not a bad plumber, but a good person who wanted to do all he could to help.

Comment: @Steven A lot of the bigger drain clearing companies don't have scopes for each truck, instead they have one or two "technicians" who operate the cameras.  So to get the technician out, it often takes another appointment.

Comment: Sounds like the plumber tried to clean the line and it may be collapsed 3 hours may be a bit long but he had to verify the problem possibly try a small snake then try a larger snake or jett. Deffinately time for a camera, this will provide info if the pipe is collapsed and the distance to the problem. I would doubt there is anything that a home owner could do at this point without the proper equipment.

Answer (score 10):

Plumbers don't have x-ray eyes, sometimes they need to scope a pipe to find the problem. This does not make him a bad/lazy plumber. It just means he doesn't carry the scope in his truck, or the company has a special technician, who is the only one who runs the camera. Let the company scope the drain so they can see what they are dealing with, at which time they will offer you options on how to correct the problem.

It could be:

- A ball of roots, that could not be broken up by the auger.
- A collapsed pipe.
- A shifted pipe.
- A large foreign object that cannot be moved by the auger.